# Change visibility of a button on a row in a listview

Tags: android, android-listview, visibility, baseadapter, android-adapter

I'm using a listview with adapter that extends BaseAdapter.
Each row in the listview has multiple views, and I want that if the value of a variable is "yes" a picture of the row is visible and if the value is "no" is gone.

But I did not succeed.

I get a forced close when changing visibilities

This is my code, any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks and regards

```
public class Adapter_c extends BaseAdapter {
...
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        View vi=convertView;

        if(convertView==null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_concursos, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.title = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.title_c);
        holder.image = (ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.image_c);
        holder.button = (Button)vi.findViewById(R.id.button_c);



        HashMap<String, String> items = new HashMap<String, String>();
        items = data.get(position);

        try { 
            String imageV = new String(items.get(FIRST_activity.KEY_STATE).getBytes("ISO-8859-1"));
            if (imageV.equals("active")){

                holder.image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else{

                holder.image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();}
...
```

Comment: trace your code,in which line your app crashes?

Comment: first try to print "imageV " string in logcat,if you are getting proper string or not

Comment: Show the LogCat please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this bunch of code :

```
if(convertView==null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_concursos, null);
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.title = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.title_c);
    holder.image = (ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.image_c);
    holder.button = (Button)vi.findViewById(R.id.button_c);
```

Like this :

```
if(convertView==null)
{
    vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_concursos, null);
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.title = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.title_c);
    holder.image = (ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.image_c);
    holder.button = (Button)vi.findViewById(R.id.button_c);        

    vi .setTag(holder);
}
else
    holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to get result without ViewHolder.

```
(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.image_c).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: what has viewholder got to do with it?

Comment: As i see you reputation i hope you know what to do.

Comment: i am waiting for op to show stacktrace. i don't think you should remove viewholder. why? check this http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html

Comment: it is reasonable after 3.0 to lower version it's make a reverse result because a ViewHolder intended on devices with normal\high perfomance to free a thread. To devices with (on example 600mhz 256ram) it's a not good way. You can don't trust me but try to check this. And you will see a little freezes on the screen.(Test 4 me - Galaxy gio)

Comment: ok good luck but i suggest you see the docs and this http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70. and where did you find its not good way for lower versions?

Comment: If I believed everything I've seen, I would not have been PL developer. Google itself keeps a lot of holes. Otherwise, Android would be the ideal system. However, this does not apply to the topic. I have work. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;


    if(convertView==null)
    {
    convertView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_concursos, parent,false);
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.title = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.title_c);
    holder.image = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.image_c);
    holder.button = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.button_c);
    convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else{
     holder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
     }
     ....some code....
       try { 
          String imageV = new String(items.get(FIRST_activity.KEY_STATE).getBytes("ISO-8859-1"));
          if(imageV.equals("active")){

             holder.image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
           } else{

              holder.image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
           }

         } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
          }
      return converView;
    }
```